# Merging polygons in SHP

Tags: ogr2ogr

Is it possible to merge polygons, using ogr2ogr cmdline tools? I.e. taking a SHP file and generate a new one, where records are merged when a field has the same value?

Comment: By using the SQLite dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html you can do everything that is supported by the SpatiaLite functions https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. Use ST_Union.

Comment: Do you have an example of a SQL setup? I have tried to create just a basic one, but all fails with various errors: ogr2ogr.exe -sql "select * from input.shp" -dialect SQLITE -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.shp

Comment: This one works: (key was to use the full path for the input data source) c:\OSGeo4W\bin\ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp -sql "select ST_UNION(GEOMETRY),ID from input group by ID" -dialect SQLITE "c:\fullpath\input.shp"

Comment: Yes, you found yourself that with shapefiles the layer name to use in FROM is the basename of the shp: input.shp -> input.