# Create multipolygons grouped by field, ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, sql, ogr2ogr

There is a large polygon data set which I would like to aggregate some of the polygons with the same values in a specific field to multipolygons.

I would like to do this using ogr2ogr. I have the following but it does not work:

`ogr2ogr -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -sql "select FIELD from singles group by FIELD" multi.shp singles.shp`

Does any one know if it is possible to do this and how?

Comment: Do you mean that a polygon feature with ID=1 having field=1, and another polygon polygon with ID=2 having field=1 would become one multipolygon feature having field=1?

Comment: Read this. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147764/merging-polygons-in-shp. You must specify -dialect SQLITE and apply ST_UNION.